# How would one create a restful URL for two different types on the same entity?

Tags: rest

So let's say you have a table called Requests. It contains requests that you submitted and also requests that other have submitted, but that you need to approve.

To load your requests, the RESTful url would probably be:

```
www.myapp.com/requests
```

For a separate link, that loads requests that I need to approve, what would the URL look like?

This is all I could come up with, but it looks sloppy:

```
www.myapp.com/requests?awaitingapproval=true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is a good implementation of filtering in a RESTful API.

This article can help you: https://blog.mwaysolutions.com/2014/06/05/10-best-practices-for-better-restful-api/

Since you are checking for a boolean, you could implement it like this also:

`www.myapp.com/requests?fields=waitingapproval`

which gives you the possibility to add other fields:

`www.myapp.com/requests?fields=waitingapproval,urgent`

Example from the site:

> GET /cars?color=red Returns a list of red cars
>
> GET /cars?seats<=2 Returns a list of cars with a maximum of 2 seats